# Docker Desktop 4.17.0 on M1 Mac is unusably slow

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, rosetta-2

I am using Docker Desktop on my MacBook Pro (with Apple M1 silicon) since October 2022 (with a Business subscription), and the performance both for Intel/AMD64 and ARM64 Linux images was really good.

Last week I updated to Docker Desktop 4.17.0 - and with that the problems started. Containers need excessive time to start (from seconds to minutes), and a docker build that ran in about 120 seconds before took 750 seconds to complete.

I tried to revert to Docker Desktop 4.16.2 (uninstall 4.17.0, install 4.16.2) - without effect. It seems that something was changed "underneath"... but other Intel binaries (applications) do not seem to be affected.

Docker Support was not helpful: they only directed me to their [Rosetta thread](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384) without providing any information about what might have happened during the Docker Desktop update from 4.16.2 to 4.17.0.

My questions:

- Did someone encounter a similar situation with Docker Desktop on a M1 Mac?
- Does someone have an idea how to get more information about what might be wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  My containers will work fine, then after a number of hours they will stop being able to communicate with each other and I can't restart them without restarting the whole of Docker Desktop.  Same hardware, running an M1 Mac

Comment: Docker has always been usually unusably slow on a Mac for me. I've always wondered why people sing its praises so much. It's completely unworkable for me.